# Thesis or a practicum at Masters Level - Computer Science

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters

I am about to reach a stage in my masters where I'll have to make a choice of doing either a regular thesis or a practicum. A practicum is simply an alternative to thesis in which a student has to submit a practical project employing the concepts developed throughout the graduate program and concludes with a paper and presentation of the crafted project.Since I am planning to apply for a PhD soon after graduation will it affect my application if I opt for the practicum instead of the thesis considering the fact that I already have published a technical paper ?

Answer (score 8):

**Thesis.**  Thesis, thesis, thesis.

(But I do agree with Suresh.  The fact that you've published is more important.)

Comment: But then a thesis and a paper would only make my application stronger as compared to thesis and practicum ? right ?

Comment: Paper > thesis > practicum.  Therefore, thesis + paper > practicum + paper > practicum + thesis.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I think the fact that you've published a technical paper would carry more weight for a CS Ph.D admissions committee than whether you did a thesis or practicum, since that's the demonstration of your ability to do research.